# What is this symbol that looks like a 3/4 circle connected to wires?

Tags: power-engineering, symbol, hvdc

I am reading an application guide related to high-voltage DC and have come across a symbol that I do not recognize:

[image]

The source of the schematic is [this document from Siemens](https://web.archive.org/web/20080408011745/http://www.rmst.co.il/HVDC_Proven_Technology.pdf).

Based on the context, my guess is that it might be either some sort of adjustable or controllable element, like a contactor or adjustable reactor, but I am not sure.

Comment: Most likely a filtering inductor.  You have AC to DC to AC link.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look further in the publication, you will find that it is a smoothing reactor.

In skimming through the document, I didn't see an explicit statement about the reactor being adjustable, but they did mention something about them being constructed with a number of "partial turns." They do say that the capacitor banks are tuned.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It is a choke (inductor).

Symbol comes from IEC60617 Symbols.

[image]